# How do I enable virtualization in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, uefi, hyper-v, hardware-virtualization

I'm doing [a Cordova tutorial](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/get-started-first-mobile-app/) and I wanted to enable Hyper-V for phone emulation. Problem was, when I went to toggle it in Control Panel, it said "Hyper-V cannot be installed: Virtualization support is disabled in the firmware." My CPU is a G2120, which supports virtualization, and I found a C:\Windows\Boot\EFI directory.

Running `systeminfo.exe` gives results ending with the following:

```
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: No
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

I haven't had any luck accessing the BIOS by pressing Del or Esc while booting up, and when I used "advanced startup" in accordance with [this how-to](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/access-bios-windows-10), "Advanced options" did *not* list "UEFI Firmware Settings".

Comment: If the motherboard's BIOS/UEFI shell does not  provide an option tio enable virtualization support, then it cannot be enabled, even if your CPU supports it.   You cannot use Hyper-V, if you cannot enable VT-x, you can use any other virtualzation product you want that doesn't have that requirement.

Comment: "did not list "UEFI Firmware Settings"." - This means it cannot be enabled on the hardware you have.  Your CPU might support it, but the firmware, **must** also support it.

Answer (score -3):

You can enable the virtualization from UEFI settings. For this in Windows 8/8.1/10 go to settings -> update and security -> recovery -> restart now (advanced options).

There you will see the advanced options -> UEFI firmware settings -> system & conf. -> virtualization

You can enable it by pressing enter.

Comment: The OP has stated that he cannot see the option you have indicated.